# I am getting the problem while deploying the sharepoint 2010 Site Definition(List Def,List instance,Fields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, site-definition, list-definition

Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Cannot complete this action.

How to solvee the issue.Exactly while actiating the list instance feature i getting the above error.

Comment: Have you checked the SharePoint ULS logs? Without some other clues no one is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any look up columns in your list,
If some columns looking to another list and  if that list has not been created so far the problem could be happen.

Comment: There could be so many other reasons too. ULS logs can give more details.